# Is it possible to simplify Serilog calls?

Tags: c#, serilog

I discovered a way to silently kill my C# program by typing Log.Error instead of Log.Logger.Error. C# happily accepts it and it swallows exceptions so the programs just goes kaput.

It would be nice to simplify it and I've tried various usings to simplify it. Things like

```
using logError = static Serilog.Log.Logger.Error;
```

But nothing that works. Is it possible?

Comment: use dependency injection to get a `ILogger`

Comment: Your application wireup either guarantees environmental invariants or it does not. The well documented standard wireup always establishes `Log.Logger` first for this reason (and there are bootstrap loggers etc). So I'd not over think this too much

Comment: I [used to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13714035/120955) recommend using dependency injection for the logger, but over time I've come to realize that the value proposition of dependency injection (testability, etc.) largely doesn't apply to cross-cutting concerns like logging. I [now recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59416660/120955) using [Fody Anotar](https://github.com/Fody/Anotar). The syntax is simply `LogTo.Error(...)`, but you get all kinds of great contextual goodness added in at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

`Log.Error()` and `Log.Logger.Error()` are the same call - one is just shorthand that forwards to the other. The source of your problem will be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

As Nicholas pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71640703), `Log.Error()` & `Log.Logger.Error()` are the same; `Log.Logger.Error()` just forward the call to `Log.Error()`. *Or is it vice versa? I forget.*

If no logger has been assigned to the static `Log.Logger` instance, then the OOB `SilentLogger` is used. Where all logging is "swallowed" by the `SilentLogger`.

If you really want to use the static `Log.Logger` instance, then a logger needs to be assigned. For example, the quickest/easiest logger to create/assign is the `ConsoleLogger`:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();
```

Once you've assigned the `ConsoleLogger`, all logging will be output to the console. Other types of loggers can be assigned as well.

Best practices would recommend using Dependency Injection, though. Review the Serilog [Configuration Basics](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics) for more information.