# Inject same scoped dependency inside itself

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

I'm learning dependency injection, because I don't want my BE to look spaghety no more. I have a good understanding of Asp.Net Core and EF Core. I just never learned dependecy injection properly. I'm playing around with an idea. Let's say, that I create an `EmailSenderService` (and `IEmailSenderService` with it). I do the same for `CustomLogger` and `WeatherRepository`. Here are the implementations:

Program.cs:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<ICustomLogger, CustomLogger>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmailSenderService, EmailSenderService>();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IWeatherRepository, WeatherRepository>();

    // Add swagger
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllers();
    app.Run();
}
```

CustomLogger.cs

```cs
public interface ICustomLogger
{
    public void Log(string logText);
}

public class CustomLogger : ICustomLogger
{
    public void Log(string logText) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(logText);
}
```

EmailSenderService.cs

```cs
public interface IEmailSenderService
{
    public void SendMail(string email, string text);
}

public class EmailSenderService : IEmailSenderService
{
    public void SendMail(string email, string text) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"TO: {email}, TEXT: {text}");
}
```

WeatherForecastModel.cs

```cs
public struct WeatherForecastModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);

    public string? Summary { get; set; }
}
```

WeatherRepository.cs

```cs
public interface IWeatherRepository
{
    public WeatherForecastModel[] GetRandomSample();
}

public class WeatherRepository : IWeatherRepository
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    public WeatherForecastModel[] GetRandomSample() =>
        Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecastModel
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        }).ToArray();
}
```

WeatherForecastController.cs

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ICustomLogger _customLogger;
    private readonly IEmailSenderService _emailSenderService;
    private readonly IWeatherRepository _weatherRepository;

    public WeatherForecastController(ICustomLogger customLogger, IEmailSenderService emailSenderService, IWeatherRepository weatherRepository)
    {
        _customLogger = customLogger;
        _emailSenderService = emailSenderService;
        _weatherRepository = weatherRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecastModel> Get()
    {
        _customLogger.Log("Started function GetWeatherForecast");
        WeatherForecastModel[] results = _weatherRepository.GetRandomSample();
        _customLogger.Log("Started sending mail.");
        _emailSenderService.SendMail("some.mail@domain.com", $"Summary of the first result: {results[0].Summary}");
        _customLogger.Log("Ended sending mail.");
        _customLogger.Log("Ended function GetWeatherForecast");
        return results;
    }
}
```

Now, with the whole implementation, in place, I don't like it. Like visually. I do not want to see logging and email sending logic inside of my controller. This is the fundamentaly issue, I'm trying to solve with this question. I could (I implemented it for testing) inject logger inside the `EmailSenderService` and inside the `WeatherRepository` and log there, howerver, I do not like that either. I do not want to see logging inside of my logic. So, I thought about something I called `LogAwareEmailSenderService`. Here is impelementation:

```cs
public class LogAwareEmailSenderService : IEmailSenderService
{
    private readonly ICustomLogger _customLogger;
    private readonly IEmailSenderService _emailSenderService;

    public LogAwareEmailSenderService(ICustomLogger customLogger, IEmailSenderService emailSenderService)
    {
        _customLogger = customLogger;
        _emailSenderService = emailSenderService;
    }

    public void SendMail(string email, string text)
    {
        _customLogger.Log($"Started sending email to: {email}, containing text: {text}");
        _emailSenderService.SendMail(email, text);
        _customLogger.Log($"Done sending email to: {email}, containing text: {text}");
    }
}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve, is: Take my original `EmailSenderService`, then inject it into my `LogAwareEmailSenderService`. The idea is, that now, I should be able to inject this `LogAwareEmailSenderService` into my controller without the need to change my controller at all (just remove my previous logging logic), right? And If I achieve this, I can go on and continue, to make something like `LogAndEmailAwareWeatherRepository`, that will inject `LogAwareEmailSenderService` and instead of sending mail and logging function start inside of the controller. I will just call `LogAndEmailAwareWeatherRepository`, that will log these things, and send the email, resulting in controller only calling the important, `_weatherRepository.GetRandomSample()` -- This call will do the logging and sending mail, using the previously described abstractions.

However, in the first place, I am unable to inject the `EmailSenderService` inside the `LogAwareEmailSenderService`. I want them both to be scoped. I trid this approach (in my Program.cs):

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmailSenderService, EmailSenderService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmailSenderService, LogAwareEmailSenderService>();
```

however I got circular dependency error:

```
'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: DependencyInjectionExample.Services.EmailSenderService.IEmailSenderService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: DependencyInjectionExample.Services.EmailSenderService.LogAwareEmailSenderService': A circular dependency was detected for the service of type 'DependencyInjectionExample.Services.EmailSenderService.IEmailSenderService'.
DependencyInjectionExample.Services.EmailSenderService.IEmailSenderService(DependencyInjectionExample.Services.EmailSenderService.LogAwareEmailSenderService) -> DependencyInjectionExample.Services.EmailSenderService.IEmailSenderService)'
```

So, I got some questions:

1. Am I going about this right? Like, is what I described above, the normal approach to things?
2. Where should I put my Logging logic? When doing this, I also thought about caching things, meaning, that I would have something like `CacheAwareWeatherRepository`, that would only care about the caching implementation and then call the WeatherRepository to get data and return them, while caching them.
3. How to implement my solution?
4. I still don't understand some parts of dependecy injection, are there any articles/books that helped you personally understand it?

If you've got here, thank you, I know it is long, however I wanted to describe my problem, possible solutions, and questions clearly.

If you have any questions, about anything, please feel free to ask me in comments, or email me (if it's long question) to dibla.tomas@email.cz. I would really like to get to the bottom of this.

PS: This is not about implementation of bussiness logic, or anything like this, this is only for getting data, logging it, caching it and doing abstractions above data access. I implemented this, with idea that you would have one interface and then layers of abstractions. One for getting the actual data (`fAb`), One for logging the fact (`sAb`) implementing `fAb`, One for caching data (`tAb`) implementing `sAb`, One for logging the fact of caching (`qAb`) implementing `tAb`. And so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I going about this right? Like, is what I described above, the normal approach to things?

There's not a right/wrong, but what you're describing is an accepted pattern, called the *decorator pattern*. One service adds behaviors around another one while implementing the same interface.

> Where should I put my Logging logic?

Depends on what you mean by "logging logic." The true *logic* of your logging (opening files and writing to them, e.g.) is already abstracted away behind the logger interface, as it should be.

If you like to have generic messages logged every time a public method is entered or exited, then you can [do that with an aspect-oriented Fody Weaver](https://canro91.github.io/2018/07/18/AOPWithFody/) to avoid repetitive code.

The lines of code that decide what to output as a log message, on the other hand, are mostly going to be specific to your implementation.  The most useful diagnostic messages are probably going to be ones that need to know contextual information about your specific implementation, and that code needs to be embedded within the implementation code itself. The fact that you "visually don't want to see" calls to the logging service in your controller code is something you should get over. Diagnostic logging is a cross-cutting concern: a responsibility inherent to every class regardless of what their "single responsibility" is supposed to be.

> How to implement my solution?

The DI registration method can take a delegate that lets you be more specific about how the type is resolved.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<EmailSenderService>(); // allow the next line to work
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmailSenderService>(p => new LogAwareEmailSenderService(
    p.GetRequiredService<ICustomLoggerService>(),
    p.GetRequiredService<EmailSenderService>()));
```

> I still don't understand some parts of dependecy injection, are there any articles/books that helped you personally understand it?

Technically not the sort of question we're supposed to be asking on StackOverflow, but I learned from Mark Seeman's [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://amzn.to/3aEZRR6) (affiliate link). It's kind of old now, so library-specific details are outdated, but the principles are enduring.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answear. I am accepting this, as it explained to me basically everything I asked for. However, I took a look into the first reference you linked (aspect programming), and I was unable to figure out (didn't spend a lot of time on it though, around 15min), how does `Log` get passed into the `OnMethodBoundaryAspect` impl? Is there way to pass my custom Log implementation inside of there? Can I inject other dependencies inside of it? I've implemented custom Attribute only once or twice in C#, do Attributes behave same (in terms of Dependecy Injection) as Controller/Services?

Comment: The aspect-oriented model doesn't support dependency injection: you'd have to get the logger instance by some other means, like a _service locator_. IMO, that's [acceptable for diagnostic logging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13714035/120955) because the messages you log aren't typically part of the spec for how the service behaves, so you don't usually want to unit test them, for example.

Comment: Honestly, I don't use the aspect-oriented approach because I don't typically log entry and exit points on my methods. I find that a combination of fail-fast code and occasionally catching and wrapping exceptions with contextual data usually gives me the information I need when I'm trying to diagnose an issue, without creating a lot of noise and overhead from excessive logging.

Comment: Good to know, this is mostly an excercise, and I do agree with you on the points you made agains aspect-oriented, howerver, as I develop mostly internal webapps I sometimes find myself wanting/needing to log specific endpoints/functions, for internal reasons. Aspect oriented aproach seems really interesting for this. Shame it does not support dependecy injection, however the alternative you provided seems promising. I'll keep it in mind for future research. One again, thank you for your helpfullness and have a good day :)

Comment: In terms of logging endpoints (controller actions), [there are built-in loggers that should already handle logging those](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#dependency-injection). You may just need to [adjust your logging configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-logging) to make sure those messages are getting emitted.

Comment: Concerning the link to the book Dependency Injection in .NET, please note that there is a second edition of that book called [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl). This edition was published 3 years ago, talks about DI in the context of .NET Core and ASP.NET Core, and I consider it to still be up to date (note that I'm the coauthor of this second edition).

Comment: Hi @Steven, I'm thinking about buying the second edition, however after reading a (very limited) preview (of chapter 2), it seems like, the book heavily relies on/uses Entity Framework (core). Personally, I tried EF, didn't liked it, and switched to Dapper (handwritten SQL is imo more flexible and sometimes easier to write, than using ORM). I intend to keep using Dapper (with Dapper.Contrib), whenever posible. How much of the book is using/relying on EF? Is it possible/recomended to read the book, and implement examples, without the use of EF? How much of DI in C# is relying on EF (in genera)?

Comment: Hi @TDiblik, in the book we try to provide DI in context. We selected architectures and tools that are common to many developers, because we think this helps in getting the message across. But keep in mind this is a book on DI and software design; the use of EF is a mere implementation detail here. By itself, there is no relationship between DI and EF.  Most examples throughout the book don't show EF at all. When you're experienced with Dapper, I'm sure you'll find little trouble in imagining those examples to use Dapper instead; EF would IMO not be a showstopper for reading the book.

Comment: Good to know, I'll give a try and see how it goes. I was just a little unsure, when I saw use of EF, with little to no prior knowledge of DI.

Answer (score 2):

I thought it might be worth mentioning the [Scrutor library](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) which lets you easily specify the decoration setup. For example, you could have:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmailSenderService, EmailSenderService>();
builder.Services.Decorate<IEmailSenderService, LogAwareEmailSenderService>();
```

*Edit*: the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) is a great way to honour [Single Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) while enabling the [Open/Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle): you're able to add new decorators to extend the capabilities of your codebase without updating the existing classes.

However, it comes with the cost of a somewhat more involved setup. The Scrutor library takes care of the decoration so that you don't need to manually code how the services are composed. If you don't have many decorators, or you don't have many levels of decoration, then that advantage might not be useful to you.

The scanning capability is not related to the decorator setup: it's simply another capability that allows one to add classes to the service collection without manually the classes (sort of auto-discovery). You can do this via reflection.

Here's an example of the decorator setup if you also had caching:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IWeatherRepository, WeatherRepository>();
builder.Services.Decorate<IWeatherRepository, DiagnosticsWeatherRepositoryDecorator>();
builder.Services.Decorate<IWeatherRepository, CachedWeatherRepositoryDecorator>();
```

You could do this manually:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<WeatherRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped(provider => new DiagnosticsWeatherRepositoryDecorator(provider.GetRequiredService<WeatherRepository>()));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IWeatherRepository>(provider => new CachedWeatherRepositoryDecorator(provider.GetRequiredService<DiagnosticsWeatherRepositoryDecorator>)));
```

It becomes a bit more involved if the constructors take other parameters. It's completely possible, but really verbose.

I thought I'd  also share some advice regarding your 5th question; my experience of dependency injection frameworks is that:

1. The frameworks are simply a key-value map; if a class needs interface A, then create class B.
2. Sometimes it's just a key; that happens when you only need to let the framework know that class C exists.
3. Whenever a class needs to be created, the map of all classes and all interface/class to class mappings are consulted, and whatever the map lists is created.
4. It seems like you're aware, but these frameworks also manage the lifetime of the objects it creates. For example, a scoped lifetime is linked to the duration of the http request. This means that an `IDisposible` object created by the framework, will be deposed once the request ends.

In your case:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmailSenderService, EmailSenderService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmailSenderService, LogAwareEmailSenderService>();
```

The second statement actually overwrites the mapping of the first statement: you can only have one key (in this case `IEmailSenderService`) in the collection. So when the framework tried to create `LogAwareEmailSenderService` it saw that `LogAwareEmailSenderService` needs an `IEmailSenderService` but the only one it knows about is `LogAwareEmailSenderService`.

This is why we only list the interface once when we manually tied up the decorated classes. When the Scrutor library is used, it re-maps the types allowing you to list the interface multiple times.

Comment: Seems nice, however are there any advantages of using it with/over base/provided api? Does it offer any features, that are difficult to achieve otherwise, or is it just a tool making it easier to use asp net core provided api? What is a difference between implementing Decorator patern "by hand" (as shown in other answear), and using this library (I am confused, as github page mentiones assembly scanning, which is not [to my knowledge] done, when implementing decorator pattern "by hand")?

Comment: I've updated my answer to give you a bit more context :)